Setting up React App from Azure AD to ADFS?
Please help me with connection my React application to adfs auth.
Before we have an authorization with using Azure Ad and MSAL.js library.
But now we need to migrate to ADFS.
What I need change in my configuration? And how configure that in ADFS?
And how configure it inside my React app?
I try to configure Aplication group in ADFS, but I don't know where to get settings of that way. What of Redirect URI?
If I try to configure Application, what about Metadata.xml and how I can get that?
P.s. ver. ADFS 2016

To connect to ADFS 2016 you have to use ADAL. There used to be a number of ADAL samples here, but the samples have been removed.
Note: ADAL is deprecated.
There are also instructions on how to configure the application. The configuration is the same in ADFS 2016 and 2019.
Note: ADAL is Open ID Connect, whereas metadata refers to WS-Fed or SAML. You don't need it.

in the article I read about incompatibility between ADFS 2016 and MSAL.js.
Has a workaround?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/desktop-mobile/adfs-support

Unfortunately in the article which you sent says:
"Applies to: Windows Server 2022, Windows Server 2019, AD FS 2019 and later"
